# How to generate a cryptographically secure pseudorandom number in C?

Tags: c, random, cryptography

I'm trying to implement a simple demonstration of [Diffie-Hellman key exchange](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diffie%E2%80%93Hellman_key_exchange) in C and i've been experimenting with the [GMP library](https://gmplib.org/) to handle large numbers.
I'm using a 2048 bit prime so i'm trying to generate a private key of 256 bits. How can i do so properly in C?

Edit: Found out about the [getrandom() syscall](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/getrandom.2.html), is this a good option?

Answer (score 1):

More portable to other UNIX flavors is the `/dev/random` and `/dev/urandom` devices.  These give data from the same pool(s) as the `getrandom` system call on Linux.

Generally you'll want to use `/dev/urandom` for most purposes.

Answer (score 0):

getrandom system call is cryptographic random number generator, it is only available on Linux.
On windows there is also CryptoGenRandom for this purpose, https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa379942(v=vs.85).aspx